# Why does FormsModule import in app.module with components in routing.module work?

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out how does angular import modules and I am not sure why would it not be able to load the forms module from the root.

```
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [AppRoutingModule, BrowserModule, TabsModule.forRoot(), FormsModule],
  providers: [ServersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and AppRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
  { path: 'servers', component: ServersComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

But I get the error from the template

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Server Name</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="name"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="serverName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="status">Server Status</label>
  <select
    id="status"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="serverStatus">
    <option value="online">Online</option>
    <option value="offline">Offline</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button
  class="btn btn-primary"
  (click)="onUpdateServer()">Update Server</button>
```

> [(ngModel)]="serverStatus" / [(ngModel)]="serverStatus" - Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'

And I understand why, I need to import the Forms module, but shouldn't Angular import it from the root `app.module`?

I also tried to put it in `routing.module` but it does not work either

I will later put these components in modules they belong to and from there it will work, but I was just wondering why it doesn't work this way?

Comment: Could you please include where the `ngModel` is defined? It seems quite likely that the template comes from a component that isn't included here, so could you please provide a [mcve] of the current issue you're facing such that we can help you?

Comment: @Edric I added but I think I am missing declarations for components in this example should they be in root.module or in routing.module?

Comment: @Edric If I put declarations in routing.module it works, but when I put them in app.module it does not. So other modules do not inherit declarations form root module but only from module where I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular can only look up the stack not down.

So if you only want to create the import of FormsModule ones put it in a shared Module that gets imported in child Modules (with an export of it).
Without it being imported into the child modules, it does not know about the existence.

Comment: But where do I declare components in the routing module or app module? It was from my understanding that if I declare them on the root module they should be available  to every child module

Comment: You are right, but I taught if I declare them in root that they would be available to routing module, which they are not

Comment: Services are the only thing that can be exposed that way.  Components need to be put into a module, and if they need to be used in more than one module then import the first module (where the first has an export).

Comment: I understand that. What I didn't know is that if I want to use components in other modules that are declared in parent I have to export them so they are available to other modules. That is what was troubling me. Thank you!!!